# Cannot preview in this file - [App Name].app may have crashed on Xcode 11 Beta 5

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swiftui, xcode11

The Xcode preview does not work if i add a `EnviromentObject` property wrapper. Everytime i add one the Canvas doesn't build and i get this error:

> Cannot preview in this file - [App Name].app may have crashed

If i replace the `EnviromentObject` property wrapper with `ObservedObject` and initialize it everything works fine.

Here's my code:

```
class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {

}

struct ContentView : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var networkManager: NetworkManager

    var body: some View {
        Text("Canvas not working")
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(NetworkManager())
    }
}
#endif
```

Update:

It doesn’t load the preview as well when i am using a binding:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var networkManager: NetworkManager
    @Binding var test123: String

    var body: some View {
        Text("Canvas not working")
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State static var test1 = ""
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(test123: $test1).environmentObject(NetworkManager())
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Your example builds and previews fine for me in Beta 5.  Can you confirm that the actual example you posted crashes?  I'm guessing you didn't include the entire NetworkManager.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming based on the code you provided that your `SceneDelegate` looks like this:

```swift
if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

I'm not going to pretend I know exactly what the canvas is doing behind the scenes when it generates a preview, but based on the fact that the error specifically states that the app may have crashed, I'm assuming that it's attempting to launch the entire app when it tries to generate a preview. Maybe it needs to use the `SceneDelegate` to launch the preview, maybe it's something else entirely - I can't say for sure.

Regardless, the reason the app is crashing is because you aren't passing an environment object in your `SceneDelegate`. Your `SceneDelegate` should look like this:

```swift
if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView().environmentObject(NetworkManager()))
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: That's correct but in my real application where i have lots of views presenting each other with .enviromentObject() it still doesn't load the preview. See my updated question where it doesn’t load the preview as well when i use a binding

Comment: The update to your question doesn't actually change anything. The `@Binding` property is irrelevant to the problem you're having. My answer does actually fix the problem if in fact your app is just a `ContentView` launched by your `SceneDelegate` as your example code implies. It's impossible for me to give you an answer regarding your real application if the code you provided in your question does not accurately represent the structure of your app.

Comment: i know that but how can i fix this binding thing

Comment: The `@Binding` property is irrelevant - that's my point. The binding property is not what's broken about your example code. The preview already wasn't loading before you added the binding property, so why would it load after?

Comment: the previous issue was fixed by adding .envObj() to the scenedelegate. But now its not working if i add a `binding ` property

Comment: But did you also pass a binding property to your `ContentView` from your `SceneDelegate`? If you didn't, then your code shouldn't even compile, but if you did, then I don't understand what the problem is because my version of your example code works just fine if I add the .envObj() and pass a binding property to `ContentView` in `SceneDelegate`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197650/discussion-between-graycampbell-and-jsbeginnernodejs).

Comment: I reviewed your flag. The edit is fine. It's within the timeframe of you both discussing the problem.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Thanks - just wanted to make sure this was staying relevant

Comment: @graycampbell I wanted to explain why the flag was marked helpful, yet I didn't take any action :)

Answer (score 9):

As @graycampbell suggested, you need to ensure that the EnvironmentObject is provided to your ContentView in the SceneDelegate. While a lot of the preview / canvas mechanics are in a black box, Xcode's UI would suggest that invoking a new preview or refreshing an existing one, builds (or updates relevant parts of) a variant of your app even for the regular preview, as opposed to the "Live Preview". This process can fail if the SceneDelegate isn't set up correctly.

For your @Binding problem, Binding.constant(_:) should help. Per the [SwiftUI Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/3134578-constant) .constant does the following:

> Creates a binding with an immutable value.

This is what you want for your preview, instead of the @State your sample code shows. You can see an example of .constant in use in Section 3 of [this Apple tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/working-with-ui-controls).

So instead of this:

```
#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State static var test1 = "Some Preview String"
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(test123: $test1)
             .environmentObject(NetworkManager())
    }
}
#endif
```

you can do the following:

```
#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(test123: .constant("Some Preview String"))
            .environmentObject(NetworkManager())
    }
}
#endif
```

With this change, previews of your code work perfectly for me.
Keep in mind that you again need to provide a value to this Binding in your SceneDelegate or any other place in which you use this particular ContentView. Otherwise you will run into a problem similar to the one you faced with EnvironmentObject, just that this particular omission luckily is highlighted by a compiler error.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and I found out what the reason was.
I simply forgot to add the `.environmentObject()` modifier 
to `ContentView()` in the preview part.

```
struct Content_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
       ContentView().environmentObject(NetworkManager())
    }
}
```

That was why Xcode built it, without showing a code-mistake, 
but crashed on preview in canvas. - Simple mistake, I know.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Xcode issue. Try to use blue button instead of "Try Again".
[image]

Comment: The issue is that this doesn't appear

Answer (score 0):

I do have a **workaround** for this, but yes that's true that bug is in XCode.
To fix this. you must set up your `SceneDelegate` first.

```
if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView().environmentObject(NetworkManager()))
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}.
```

You must set up your preview too. As seems you have already done that.

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(NetworkManager())
    }
}.
```

At last, just declare one `@State` variable inside your `ContentView`, of the same type you `@Published` your `@EnvironmentObject`, whether or not you use it for binding anywhere in `ContentView` doesn't matter.

```
@State var bindingVar: Double = 0.0
```

As I said earlier that it's XCode bug and I don't know why `ContentView` needs one @State variable of the same type to start previewing `@EnvironmentObject` bound code.
May be `ContentView_Previews` unable to find out binding from `@EnvironmentObject`.

You can see below in my code, it works like a charm.

[image]